# Unable to extract the text content from pdf file using tika

Tags: fonts, ghostscript, apache-tika, postscript

I am using a Postscript printer which generates a '.ps' file,and I am converting this .ps file into .pdf using 'ps2pdf' command in my linux machine.The file which is generated here, it's content is not selectable and copyable .Also when I try to extract the content from same pdf file using apache Tika it return an empty string (means not able to extract).I thought it might be problem with some fonts,so I installed some new fonts also but still it didn't work for me.

I am not able to find out what the problem is.Whether it is problem with printer driver or ghostscript (which is being used to convert '.ps' into '.pdf') or it is problem with fonts or something-else.

while retrieving content using tika it is printing some warning (not errors) as below.

```
WARN  No Unicode mapping for CID+1 (1) in font WKQJKU+ArialNarrow-Identity-H
WARN  No Unicode mapping for CID+2 (2) in font WKQJKU+ArialNarrow-Identity-H
WARN  No Unicode mapping for CID+3 (3) in font WKQJKU+ArialNarrow-Identity-H
WARN  No Unicode mapping for CID+4 (4) in font WKQJKU+ArialNarrow-Identity-H
WARN  No Unicode mapping for CID+5 (5) in font WKQJKU+ArialNarrow-Identity-H
```

....

Any help is appreciated .Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing the original PostScript file and the PDF its not really possible to tell what the problem is, or if it can be fixed. You need to post the files somewhere public.

You also don't say exactly what the 'ps2pdf' command is, there are several different utilities that use the same name. If its using Ghostscript then it will say so when running. If so you would do better to run Ghostscript directly to avoid confusion. You should also quote the version of Ghostscript you are using.

Now PostScript programs are normally intended to be sent to printers for printing. As such it does not matter what character codes are used to represent a glyph, provided that the font Encoding and the character code combine to produce the expected character shape on output. So there is absolutely no guarantee that an 'A' in your original application, which gets printed as an 'A' on paper is actually represented by character code 0x41 for example. Its not uncommon for an application to create a subset font, which only contains the glyphs actually printed, and which is arranged so that the first character to be printed is given the code 1, the second is given the code 2 etc. Thus 'Hello' would be 0x01 0x02 0x03 0x03 0x04

The Windows PostScript printer driver adds a non-standard G2U table, which maps glyph names to Unicode code points, and using this it is possible to construct a ToUnicode CMap and embed that in the PDF file. This allows complex Encodings to be converted into Unicode values, which means that search and copy/paste will work.

But You haven't said which system you are using to create the PostScript program, and since you haven't supplied an example, we simply don't know how your PostScript is being generated.

It does appear that your PDF file is using a CIDFont, and does not contain a ToUnicode CMap. Its fairly unlikely that this will yield a PDF file where you can copy/paste stuff. Of course, that wasn't the original goal of PDF anyway, which is why its not guaranteed to be possible.

It may well be that there simply is no way to turn the PostScript file into an editable PDF file, but you haven't supplied enough information to tell.

[later]

The PostScript is produced by Cairo, possibly from a PDF file, but that's not totally clear, it may simply be the way that Cairo works. In any event.... The PostScript contains an embedded subset CIDFont with CIDFontType 2 (TrueType outlines). Because PostScript doesn't have a defined mechanism for supplying Unicode information there is none supplied. As described above, the 'encoding' is created as the characters are encountered, so the first glyph is encoded as 0x01 etc.

The result of this is that there is no simple way to extract meaningful text from this PostScript file, other than printing it and using OCR of course.

Its just conceivable that the sfnts of the CIDFont contains a 3,0 CMAP subtable which would map the glyph IDs to Unicode values, but it would take me some time to check.

However, even if that is the case, Ghostscript's pdfwrite code doesn't currently attempt that feat (nor does Acrobat Distiller, nor any other PostScript to PDF creator that I'm aware of).

So, fundamentally, you can't do what you're trying to do. Why not have Cairo produce a PDF file instead of a PostScript file ? Its more likely to work that way I would have thought. Of course that would probably mean you'll have to look at how your virtual printer works, if you are using CUPS it should be possible I would have thought, since PDF is the itnernal format used by modern versions of CUPS.

Comment: Hi @KenS ,Thank you so much for your quick response, in my question 'ps2pdf' is ghostscript utility and printer is in linux machine .I don't know how to upload the file here for reference.If you share your mail id I can send you the file also.

Comment: You can't post files here, better to put it on DropBox or something and post a URL here, then people other than me can look. What version of Ghostscript are you using, and where did you get it (package, built from source yourself etc) ? If you absolutely must use email you can send to ken at spamcop dot net (don't want to put an obvious email address in here)

Comment: Hi @KenS ,My ghostscript version is 9.16 .Here I am sharing dropbox links to postscript and pdf files . https://www.dropbox.com/s/jq5m4dkz175o0nk/VirtualPrinter_16_08_2016_16_09_20_865.ps?dl=0 , https://www.dropbox.com/s/y8jo3whu2kw12sr/VirtualPrinter_16_08_2016_16_09_24_896.pdf?dl=0

Comment: I believe there's a hard limit of 32k in these posts. For hand-written postscript, it can usually go in a code-block. For generated ps, the files are often too huge, but the first 20 lines or so often have the crucial information. So adding the output of `head sthg.ps` in a code-block can be helpful to get to the answer quicker FWIW.